# Python 3 CSV file nominees

Tags: python, string, csv, dictionary

```
import csv

title = input('Winning title: ')

with open('nominees.csv', newline='') as f:
  for line in csv.DictReader(f):
     print('Congratulations: ',line['director(s)'])
```

This code outputs:

```
Winning title: O brother, Where Art Thou?
Congratulations:  Steven Spielberg
Congratulations:  Joel Coen, Ethan Coen
Congratulations:  Stanley Kubrick
Congratulations:  Buster Keaton, Roscoe Arbuckle
```

I'm trying to get it to output this:

```
Winning title: O Brother, Where Art Thou?
Congratulations: Joel Coen, Ethan Coen
```

I know I am missing a bunch of code...for loop???

Comment: Share your csv input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

```
with open('nominees.csv', newline='') as f:
  for line in csv.DictReader(f):
    print('Congratulations: ',line['director(s)'])
```

to

```
with open('nominees.csv', newline='') as f:
  for line in csv.DictReader(f):
    if line['title'] == title:
      print('Congratulations: ',line['director(s)'])
```